# Django-Rest-Framework - How to Deserialize Custom Nested Field

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework, deserialization

I have a model called 'Invite' that searches for an existing user and creates one if they do not already exist:

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
from users.models import CustomUser

class Hangout(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class InviteManager(models.Manager):
  def create_invite(self, hangout, phone):
    (user, did_create) = CustomUser.objects.get_or_create(phone=phone)
    invite = self.create(status=status, hangout=hangout, arrival_time=arrival_time, user=user)
    return invite

class Invite(models.Model):
  hangout = models.ForeignKey(Hangout, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='invites')
  user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser)

  objects = InviteManager()
```

I am having a lot of trouble deserializing it.  I'd like to create a hangout with nested invites with this post request:

```
{ 'name': 'Bobs House',
  'invites': [
             { 'phone': '5127914819', 'name': 'Bob1' },
             { 'phone': '0000000000', 'name': 'Bob2' },
             { 'phone': '0000000001', 'name': 'Bob3' },
             { 'phone': '0000000002', 'name': 'Bob3' },
             { 'phone': '0000000003', 'name': 'Bob4' }
             ]
}
```

I want the Invite serializer to check that phone exists and is 10 digits long.  I am having a lot of trouble setting up a sequence of serializers to work.  I have tried combinations of the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30765360/how-to-deserialize-nested-objects-with-django-rest-framework) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22958058/how-to-change-field-name-in-django-rest-framework), but the combination of nested deserializers and custom create fields that are not on the model at all is driving me nuts.  Any help is much appreciated!  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using an serializer with different fields than those on the model.  Here is the working code in case it helps someone:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from . import models
from users.models import CustomUser

class InviteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  phone = serializers.CharField()
  name = serializers.CharField(required=False)

  class Meta:
    extra_kwargs = { 'name': { 'read_only': True },
                     'phone': { 'read_only': True }}

    fields = (
      'phone',
      'name',
      )
    model = models.Invite

  def validate(self, data):
    return data

  def create(self, validated_data):
    phone = validated_data.pop('phone')
    name = validated_data.pop('name', None)
    (user, did_create) = CustomUser.objects.get_or_create(phone=phone)
    if (user.display_name is None) and (name is not None):
      user.display_name = name
    user.save()
    instance = self.Meta.model.objects.create(user=user, hangout=validated_data['hangout'])
    instance.save()

class HangoutSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  name = serializers.CharField(required=True)
  invites = InviteSerializer(many=True)

  class Meta: 
    extra_kwargs = { 'phones': {'write_only': True, 'required': True } }

    fields = (
      'invites',
      'name',
      )

    model = models.Hangout

  def create(self, validated_data):
    invites_data = validated_data.pop('invites')
    instance = self.Meta.model(**validated_data)
    instance.save()

    serializer = InviteSerializer(data=invites_data, many=True)
    if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
      invites = serializer.save(hangout=instance)
      return instance
```